# Report builder 3.0 cannot figure out how to make the correct expression

Tags: ssrs-2008

I want to show in the report builder a string with the values from different rows that belong to the same id separating them by `,` for example:

```
id person= 1 , phone1
id person= 1 , phone2
```

So in the report builder I can show

```
person phones
1      phone1 ,phone2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this by creating a group on the "id person" field and in "phones" columns use the expression =join(fields!id_person.value,",")